# Ubuntu unity-control-center shows high virtual memory

Tags: 16.04, unity-control-center

Ubuntu 16.04, `unity-control-center network` is requesting a 113G virtual memory which I find unusual, not sure how to debug this or how to solve this. I understand that virtual memory has nothing to do with the amount of physical memory being used, but I find this suspicious.

[image]